# Knockout JS not binding

Tags: knockout.js

I'm working on an Order screen, normal master/detail scenario.

All my models are pulled from the server and mapped using Knockout Mapping plugin. Everything works fine, including when I get several rows from the server - they all displayed correctly.

But when I want to add a new row - Knockout seem to completely ignore newly added line.

I have simulated same situation without server-side models:

```
<div id="container">My order
<table data-bind="with: currentRecord">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Lines">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="button" data-bind="click: $root.newLine">New line</button>
            </td>
            <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
function LineModel(idValue) {
    var self = this;

    self.Id = ko.observable(idValue);
}

function OrderModel() {

    var self = this;

    self.currentRecord = ko.observable();

    self.currentRecord.Lines = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.newLine = function () {
        self.currentRecord.Lines.push(new LineModel(12));
    };

    self.newLine();
}

ko.applyBindings(new OrderModel());
```

JSFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/serman/84aug/10/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Knockout model `currentRecord` is an observable so you need to reference it like this:

`self.currentRecord().Lines.push(new LineModel(12));`

Comment: For the record, I'm always making this oversight. If in doubt, add parentheses :)

Answer (score 0):

You are suffering from not knowing when to use parentheses itus.  I suffered from this alot when I first got into ko, but to put it simply you are missing a set of parentheses on the lines below.

```
self.currentRecord.Lines = ko.observableArray([]);  // and
self.newLine = function () {
    self.currentRecord.Lines.push(new LineModel(12));
};
```

should be

```
 self.currentRecord().Lines = ko.observableArray([]); // and
 self.newLine = function () {
    self.currentRecord().Lines.push(new LineModel(12));
};
```

and you also have to provide you self.currentRecord with an object to extend

```
self.currentRecord = ko.observable({});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/84aug/13/